# controlling display coordinates of view item added to toolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to have precise control over the custom view I add to my UINavigationController toolbar. More specifically.. i want to display a UILable *ontop* of the items in my toolbar.

I have a `toolbarItems` initially set up with some `UIBarButtonItems`. The effect I'm trying to achieve is programmatically expand the height of the toolbar, and then display a `UILabel` ontop of the rest of the buttons.. this is what I currently have:

```
-(void)expandToolBar:(NSString *)title {

    UIToolbar* toolBar =self.navigationController.toolbar;
    CGRect toolbarFrame = toolBar.frame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{

        // expand toolbar frame vertically
        [toolBar setFrame:
         CGRectMake(toolbarFrame.origin.x,
                    toolbarFrame.origin.y-15,
                    toolbarFrame.size.width,
                    toolbarFrame.size.height + 15)];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
            // some code here to move the existing toolbar items lower
            // ie to make space for the label

            UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
            [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            label.text = title;

            UIBarButtonItem *labelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                             initWithCustomView:label];

            // add label to toolbar
            NSMutableArray *newItems = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
            [newItems addObject:labelItem];
            self.toolbarItems = newItems;
        }];
    }];
}
```

the result of this is that all the existing buttons get squashed, and the label takes their place. The problem is that If I try to get a little too creative and start manually messing with the subviews of the toolbar, I start wandering into undocumented API land, [something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/782679/766570) Apple won't [tolerate](http://seattleclouds.com/ticketfiles/8665/ios_program_standard_agreement_20120912.pdf). Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your actual question? If what you're doing is *legal* or not? I use some similar tricks to get from the UIBarButtonItem to the view that is represented from it, and it has never been a problem.

For example, I use following snippet without any issues. Technically this isn't using private API per so, but relying on undocumented view structure and here also part of the class names, so you *really* should know what you're doing. Please also file a radar that UIBarButtonItem is messed up and misses an obvious flag to get to the actual view.

```
static UIView *PSToolbarViewForBarButtonItem(UIToolbar *toolbar, UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem) {
    UIView *barButtonView = nil;
    for (UIControl *subview in toolbar.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) hasPrefix:@"UIToolbarB"] && [subview isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
            for (UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem in [subview allTargets]) {
                if (barButtonItem == aBarButtonItem) { barButtonView = subview; break; }
            }
        }
    }
    return barButtonView;
}
```

Also, if you go that route, write code that will fail gracefully if for any reason the view for the toolbar can't be found. I know some apps that go my route, while lots of others don't even bother and simply write their own code to create a toolbar.

Comment: my specific question is that i want to display a UILable ontop of the items in my toolbar.. also what's 'praxis'?

Comment: the problem with your solution is that even if I get to adjust the properties of the UILabel as I like.. the other buttons will still get squished b/c they assume that there is a fourth button.. i'm gonna look at the creating my own toolbar option..

Comment: Abood, simply manually add a view onto the toolbar and manage the views. But really, what you're trying to do is quite hard with a UIToolbar. This isn't the most flexible class.