# How do I set the color for the editButtonItem in the navigation bar of a UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableViewController where I added a "editButtonItem" in the navigation bar :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

No magic here, but I try to define the color (background and foreground/textcolor) of this button.

I read in the Apple forum somewhere that the button changes the color if I change the navigationbar to the same color, well despite the fact that I do not get this to work either (for testing) I do not want to touch the navigationbr itself, just the button.

Since this button is already predefined I am not sure how to handle this. Do I need to overwrite the button with my own definition or can I just simply apply a new style (if so how ?)

Thx

Comment: Is the `editButtonItem` a UIBarButtonItem? If so, is it initialized with the method `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:` or `initWithTitle:`?

Comment: actually the editButtonItem is a predefined UIBarButtonItem from the UIViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything fails, you can tint the bar in the viewDidLoad of your childViewController

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:50 saturation:50 brightness:.2 alpha:.5]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can find to make a UIBarButtonItem with a different color is to use a custom view and the `initWithCustomView:` method. Predefined buttons and those created using `initWithTitle:target:action:` cannot change their background color.

Take a look at this SO question: [UIBarButtonItem with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

These links might also help:
[http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/...](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/33286-color-image-uibarbuttonitem-uitoolbar.html)
[http://www.insanelymac.com/...](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=123010)