# How can I change the font color of a UIBarButton item?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the color to red.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIBarButtonItem with color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color).  Basically, you have to create a UIButton, configure it as you wish, and then initialize the Bar Button Item with the UIButton as a custom view.

Answer (score 104):

I found a simpler way to just change the color of title:
iOS7:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = 
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                 target:nil 
                                 action:nil];
[button setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
               [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] 
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and prior iOS7:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                  target:nil 
                                  action:nil];
[button setTitleTextAttributes:
          [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
               [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] 
                                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Certainly a good solution if you are iOS 5.0 or greater. OP: Check out UIBarItem.h for details.

Comment: I have been searching for ages to find out how to change text color, thanks a lot!!. Luckily majority of phones are on IOS5 now so this is not really a concern

Comment: i have fixed this answer for iOS7

Comment: Thanks @Gavy, it's working fine. Can you tell me how to change the font of title?

Comment: @AnandGautam You can use the UITextAttributeFont attribute to change the font.

Answer (score 8):

There are Two ways to change the color of the Text displayed UIBarButtonITem.

1)

```
[barButtonITem setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

2) or you can you any UIColor class method. this is really efficient solution.Althought for iOS 7     you can use NSForegroundColorAttributeName  and can use

```
barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor clearColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 3):

On similar note from  Guvvy Ava you can change font size like

```
[buttonItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:26.0], UITextAttributeFont,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

swift version 4.0 or later

```
barButtonITem.tintColor = UIColor.red   // for textColor change
```

if want to change font as well as text color use the following code

```
barButtonITem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor :UIColor.red,NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.init(name:"Avenir", size:15.0)], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using system Navigation bar button item then to change your button tint color use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

To change button text color use the following code also.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Add the following line of code which viewcontroller you want to change your color