# How to change the font color / Text Color of the UIBarButtonItem on navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I add a bar button to the navigation bar programitically as follows

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"CANCEL" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goToPreviousView)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancel;
```

Now I want to display **Text "CANCEL" in RED Color**.

I mean that I need to change the **text on the bar button items**, but not the tint color of the button.

How to do that?

Comment: Check out these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314035/how-can-i-change-the-font-color-of-a-uibarbutton-item and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color

Comment: For iOS 5+, see this answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810563/how-do-you-use-settitletextattributesforstate-in-uibaritem-in-ios-5-0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another method is :-

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"delete.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12.0f];
[button.layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
[button.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[button.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[button.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 60.0, 30.0);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(batchDelete)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem* deleteItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Answer (score 107):

Check this out :-

```
  UIBarButtonItem *cancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[cancel setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor redColor],  UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: it causes to crash:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACESS (code=2 address=0x0)

Comment: +1 it works perfect .thanks .@ user1645721 setTitleTextAttributes function available from IOS 5

Comment: It should be noted that `UITextAttributeTextColor` was replaced with `NSForegroundColor` in 7.0.

Comment: NSForegroundColorAttributeName is the correct replacement for UITextAttributeTextColor

Answer (score 33):

Just an iOS7 Update with Modern Obj-C Syntax:

```
[barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 13):

```
UITextAttributeTextColor //Is deprecated on iOS 7.
```

This code is used for change the text color from from appearance proxy.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: This sets background color, he asked for text color.

Comment: Use NSForegroundColorAttributeName instead of UITextAttributeTextColor

Answer (score 9):

Here is updated swift 4.0 version code :

```
let reset = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Reset All", style: .plain , target: self, action: #selector(self.resetButtonClicked(_ :) ))
reset.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 4):

this code is used for change the text color of the UIBarButtonItem on the navigation bar:

```
UILabel *lblTotCaratteri = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 25)];
lblTotCaratteri.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
lblTotCaratteri.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
lblTotCaratteri.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
lblTotCaratteri.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTotCaratteri.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
lblTotCaratteri.text = @"Cancel";

UIBarButtonItem *lblCaratteri = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: lblTotCaratteri];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = lblCaratteri;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
doneButton.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 3):

Old question, here's the swift 2.2 solution:

```
    let cancel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CANCEL", style: .Bordered, target: self, action: #selector(goToPreviousView))
    cancel.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState: .Normal)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancel
```

Answer (score 3):

### Swift 4.2

**UIBarButtonItem using attributed text:**

```
func createCancelButton() {
        guard let font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12) else { return }
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelTapped))
        cancelButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.blue, NSAttributedString.Key.font : font], for: .normal)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
    }

    @objc func cancelTapped() {
        print("cancelTapped")
    }
```

**UIBarButtonItem using plain text:**

```
func createCancelButton() {
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelTapped))
        cancelButton.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
    }

    @objc func cancelTapped() {
        print("cancelTapped")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to set a color different from the default appearance, use:

```
barButtonItem.tintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 1):

UITextAttributeTextColor //Is deprecated on iOS 7.

Set the color of BarButtonItem in a way like this

```
    [_barButtonItem setTitleTextAttributes:
                    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             [UIColor colorWithRed:250/255.0 
                                             green:240/255.0 
                                             blue:230/255.0 
                                             alpha:1.0],  
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] 
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that everyone should do if it's not your project and you just need to add some changes - is check

```
[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
```

I wasted a lot of time to realise that someone set wrong appearance of UIBarButtonItem