# How do I change the color of a UINavigation leftBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want my leftBarButtonItem to be a red button. I haven't figured out how to do that. I'm using the following code to construct the navigation bar and button. 
Any help is appreciated.
lq

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
navBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack; 
navBar.translucent = YES;
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
[navBar release];

UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
initWithTitle:@"Clear"
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
target:self 
action:@selector(myAction:)];

navItem.leftBarButtonItem = clearButton;
[navBar pushNavigationItem:navItem animated:false];
[navBar setDelegate:self];    
[navItem release];
[clearButton release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will find a nicer solution in [this posting at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color) or you can go the way using a UISegmentedControl

```
UISegmentedControl *button = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Clear", nil]] autorelease];
button.momentary = YES;
button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
button.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
...
UIBarButtonItem *clearButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

navItem.leftBarButtonItem = clearButton;
```

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me to use a UISegmentedControl.