# UIBarButtonItem tintColor with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

I have a navigation controller with 2 UIBarButtonItems in my navigation bar. I want to change the tint color only for the one on the right. I have found a way in static to do that:

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews objectAtIndex:2] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

The problem is when I push a controller into my navigation controller to display another view, when I come back to the root view where my right navigation bar button is supposed to have a custom color, the color of the button is back to its default. And when I click again on it, the app crashes. It says it cannot change the tint color, like if the index for this element in my navigation bar changed.

I have tried other technics found on the internet, but they all failed when I use the navigation controller and come back to the root controller...

Any idea?
Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

I would like a bordered style button in my UINavigationBar, with a red or green background color.

Regarding the other ways I found, it is pretty much a foreach loop of the views in the navigation bar, and if the view's kind of class is a button item then change the tintColor. It doesn't crash but it applies to all the UIBarButtonItem of my navigation bar (and I just want a specific button, the right one, not all of them). For example [this tutorial](http://www.skylarcantu.com/blog/2009/11/05/changing-colors-of-uinavigationbarbuttons/) is half working, my app crashes when coming back to the root view controller.

Comment: Most of the time we cannot come up with a good solution, so I cannot say we solved my question. That's probably why my rate is low, and because of unanswered questions. Otherwise I credit someone if he solved or even partially helped me solving my problem...

Comment: @Erik B You make it easier for me then, you're not being helpful at all for my question. So I won't give you any credit for that. But I'll keep in mind what you said for my old and next posts, it's better to learn something rather than nothing right? Have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the subviews of the navigationcontroller.navigation bar wont fly with Apple, ...
the correct way to change the color of a UIBarButtonItem is to use a customView with the buttonitem.  here is a link that explains...

[UIBarButtonItem with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

Comment: I have tried the solution, I can have a button but not bordered like I want. And I would like to avoid to create an image to put it as background. If it is the only solution to get a bordered style with custom colors button in my navigation bar, I guess I won't have too many choices...

Comment: Use an image in the button or you can also get your hands dirty with Quartz. Let me know if u would like some code.

Answer (score 0):

You simply create a segmented control with just one segment. Set its tint color as you like. You may also want to set its mode to momentary so it optically behaves like a button. Add the segmented control to the bar button item by using the initWithCustomView: initializer. That's how you typically create custom tinted buttons.

Example:

```
UISegmentedControl *cartControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,7,60,30)];
[cartControl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.35 green:0.47 blue:0.65 alpha:1]];
[cartControl addTarget:self action:@selector(cart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[cartControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar]; 
[cartControl insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping_cart_white_small.png"] atIndex:0 animated:NO]; 
[cartControl setMomentary:YES];  

UIBarButtonItem *cartButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cartControl];
[cartControl release];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:cartButton];
[cartButton release];
```