# How can I adjust the highlight color of my UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I am using the appearance proxy to adjust my color settings globally:

```
//Setup custom appearances
    if ([UINavigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:96.0/255.0 green:13.0/255.0 blue:11.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:96.0/255.0 green:13.0/255.0 blue:11.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        //rgb: 96, 13, 11
        //[[UIToolbar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
```

This works fine, but when I tap on a UIBarButtonItem that is in my UINavigationbar, it changes color to black. How can I make sure the highlighted state is not black?

Comment: This post should help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: [UIBarButtonItem with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

Make sure that you import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" in order to access the layer properties of UIView. To import that, you need to have added the CoreGraphics framework to your project.

Answer (score 1):

last line is:

```
[[UIToolbar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

maybe rem it?

Comment: even if I remove that line my UIBarButtonItem's are black (They are in my UINavigationController btw)

Comment: What happens if you change it to redColor for instance?