# UINavigationBar BackButton custom TintColor

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, tintcolor

Hi i am trying to get another TintColor on my BackButton in my UINavigationBar. I would like to change only the tintcolor and not to replace the whole button. Are there any suggestions on implemententing this easily?

Comment: If you mean with surf, searched in the web, yeah i did. But there were only outdated entries…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using iOS5 there's a tintColor property available on UIBarButtonItem. Otherwise please check out one of the past answers such as [UIBarButtonItem with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

Comment: The main problem i got here is, that i can't access the backbarbutton. If i try to access the back button it's everytime (null).

Comment: You could try the following which using uiappearance to change all instances of uibarbuttonitem: [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
       setTintColor:myNavBarColor];