# How to add a background colour to BarButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The UINavigationBar is RedColour.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(bbPressed:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=barButton ;
```

Now i need to give a black background colour for the above BarButton. How can i do this programatically ?

I have tried this using the IB and it works, but i need to do it using code only.

Steps how to do it in IB;

change background colour to `RED`.
Change the style to - `BlackTranslucent`

I tried setting these using the code but it doesn't work.

Help

Comment: Check 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change default styles of `UIBarButton`. Use `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourView]` where `yourView` is customized `UIButton`.

Comment: Could you show me an example ?

Comment: you can check this link :http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-how-to-create-a-blue-navigation-button