# Adding a background image to UIBarButton Item using interface builder - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I added a `UIToolBar` from `Interface builder`, then dragged 2 `UIBarButtonItem's`. Now i need to add an `image` to it. So i selected the `barButtonItem` and selected the `image` using `Interfacebuilder`.

I only get a White `image`, with no curvy edge. My `image` is as follows. I don't see that image, but instead i see a white rectangle.

How do i prevent this. Can someone tell me whats wrong, and provide me with a working solution.

my bar button
[image]

Comment: What is the size (dimension) of the image you want to set as the background of the UIBarButtonItem? Maybe it is because, the image is too big to fit.

Comment: But, it should not show a white background. the size of the button is 100X35. If you have done this could you kindly share your solution. I am stuck in this for hours

Comment: I'd look @ this question, not IB, but it does the job - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color

Comment: Yes, that did but there's another problem with that which i can't use it in my project. I have tried this before, in fact the above image is from that SO question (i only changed the colour of it)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) you will see the specifications for icons and buttons. This is my experience, for the best result you'd better create a specific icon (image) for `UIBarButtonItem`. If you still want to use an image, that doesn't follow the `UIBarButtonItem` guide, my approach is:

1. Add a generic `UIButton` instance to your view. Drag it from the list on the right to the view, not to the ToolBar or navBar.
2. Customize it with the image, i.e. from the Inspector, set the image or background image, or set it to custom style, bordered, etc.
3. Drag it to the toolBar, and XCode will adjust it. Again, it does not always guarantee the best result, but it does what you want.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should drag an "Image View" on to your layout and specify the image in that - that worked for me, but I'm no xcode guru.

Hope that helps, Paul