# Getting yellow UIBarButtonItem button like Photos app?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm currently working on an UI to crop an image inside my app, and I'd like it to feel as native as possible. I looked to the iPad's built in Photos app for some ideas, and noticed that when you crop an image, instead of a blue "Done" button, it has a yellow tinted button that has "Crop" on it, like so:

[image]

Does anyone know how to replicate this? I recall that the UIKit framework had a bunch of artwork stored inside of it in some custom file format and an iOS app existed that was able to read this and save you the individual PNGs, but I do not remember what this app is called. Conveniently enough for me, the thing I remember is that this yellow button graphic was among those contained. Anyone got any ideas how I can replicate the button nevertheless?

(Although if anyone knows that utility, that'd be great.)

Comment: Try this:[UIBarbutton with color.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5