# Want to change image bar button item's image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbaritem

I have created a AVFoundation Camera,now i want to change toolbar item image to my custom image , when user tap record camera button than image will change.

I have done that change but problem is that my image display black and white no color.soplz help on this.

My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
[[self recordButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camara30.png"]]  //first time setting image
}

- (void)captureManagerRecordingBegan:(AVCamCaptureManager *)captureManager
{
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^(void) {
       // [[self recordButton] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [[self recordButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record30.png"]];   //changing image when record begun
        [[self recordButton] setEnabled:YES];
    });
}

- (void)captureManagerRecordingFinished:(AVCamCaptureManager *)captureManager
{
    CFRunLoopPerformBlock(CFRunLoopGetMain(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes, ^(void) {
        [[self recordButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camara30.png"]];   //changing image when record end
        [[self recordButton] setEnabled:YES];
    });
}
```

My first screen before start recording:

[image]

My second screen after end recording:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    UIBarButtonItem *temp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BlueMarbleDrop"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 60.0, 30.0);
    [button addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem* stopBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    [self.toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:temp,stopBtn,temp, nil]];
```

the output look like 
[image]

i took this from [UIBarButtonItem with color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color)

Comment: it does not working instead of image it displaying blank place which is clickable.

Comment: i tested this peace of code and the out put look like the image i posted. the blue dot on the top is a toolbar button...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set image
        [[self recordButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"record30.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];