# Setting the tint color works fine when in ios5 but in ios4 it gives a crash

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Here i am setting the blue color for the rightbarbuttom item it works in ios5 but not in ios4. How should i prevent the crash so that my app supports both ios4 and ios5.

Answer (score 1):

yes, @borrrden is correct, setting `tintColor` for `UIBarButtonItem` is available only after `iOS 5.0`. Check the condition before you set color to your `navigationItem`

```
#if __IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
      self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
#endif
```

Comment: you can found solution in this [link](http://fredandrandall.com/blog/2011/03/31/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem/) or you have to create manual `UIButton` and can assign to your `UIBarButtonItem` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664930/uibarbuttonitem-with-color) and you can assign that `UIBarButton` to your `rightBarButton`

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using `appearance` and `UIBarButtonItem`'s `tintColor` because they are not supported on iOS 4.x

Comment: ok would try but if i use the above code also it still crashes